# Integer type with floating point semantics for C or D

Tags: c, floating-point, int, d, fixed-point

I'm looking for an existing implementation for **C** or **D**, or advice in implementing, signed and/or unsigned **integer types** with **floating point semantics**.

That is to say, an integer type that behaves as floating point types do when doing arithmetic: **Overflow produces *infinity*** (*-infinity* for signed underflow) rather than wrapping around or having undefined behavior, **undefined operations produce *NaN***, etc.

In essence, a version of floating point where the distribution of presentable numbers falls evenly on the number line, instead of conglomerating around 0.

In addition, all operations should be **deterministic**; any given two's complement 32-bit architecture should produce the exact same result for the same computation, regardless of its implementation (whereas floating point may, and often will, produce slightly differing results).

Finally, **performance is a concern**, which has me worried about potential "bignum" (arbitrary-precision) solutions.

See also: *Fixed-point* and *saturation arithmetic*.

Comment: *"two 32-bit architectures should both produce the exact same result for the same computation"* Can we assume two's complement on all 32-bit architectures?

Comment: @Catcall Sure. As I understand it, one's complement architectures are extremely rare.

Comment: A possibly related concept, Saturating operations: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/277

Answer (score 3):

I do not know of any existing implementations of this.

But I would imagine implementing it would be a matter of (in D):

```
enum CheckedIntState : ubyte
{
    ok,
    overflow,
    underflow,
    nan,
}

struct CheckedInt(T)
    if (isIntegral!T)
{
    private T _value;
    private CheckedIntState _state;

    // Constructors, getters, conversion helper methods, etc.

    // And a bunch of operator overloads that check the
    // result on every operation and yield a CheckedInt!T
    // with an appropriate state.

    // You'll also want to overload opEquals and opCmp and
    // make them check the state of the operands so that
    // NaNs compare equal and so on.
}
```

Comment: How would you go about checking overflows, etc.?

Comment: I don't have time to extract an example right now, but there's some code here that you can go by: https://github.com/lycus/darepl/blob/master/src/darepl/epiphany/emulation/arithmetic.d

Answer (score 2):

Saturating arithmetic does what you want except for the part where undefined operations produce NaN; this is going to turn out to be problematic, because most saturating implementations use the full number range, and so there are not values left over to reserve for NaN.  Thus, you probably can't easily build this on the back of saturating hardware instructions unless you have an additional "is this value NaN" field, which is rather wasteful.

Assuming that you're wedded to the idea of NaN values, all of the edge case detection will probably need to happen in software.  For most integer operations, this is pretty straightforward, especially if you have a wider type available (let's assume `long long` is strictly larger than whatever integer type underlies `myType`):

```
myType add(myType x, myType y) {
    if (x == positiveInfinity && y == negativeInfinity ||
        x == negativeInfinity && y == positiveInfinity)
        return notANumber;
    long long wideResult = x + y;
    if (wideResult >= positiveInfinity) return positiveInfinity;
    if (wideResult <= negativeInfinity) return negativeInfinity;
    return (myType)wideResult;
}
```

Comment: I won't have a wider type available; that's kind of the point.

Comment: @CoreXii: there is always a wider type available, it's just a matter of how much work you need to do to implement its operations =)

Comment: You mean, for example, presenting a 64-bit type with two 32-bit ones?

Comment: Yes, like that; of course, you won't need to actually implement the full operations for the wider type.  Your inputs are known to be narrow, and you don't need to compute the high-part (as soon as you know there *is* a high part, you know the result is just +/-inf).

Answer (score 2):

One solution might be to implement multiple-precision arithmetic with abstract data types. The book *C Interfaces and Implementations* by David Hanson has a chapter (interface and implementation) of MP arithmetic.

Doing calculations using scaled integers is also a possibility. You might be able to use his arbitrary-precision arithmetic, although I *believe* this implementation can't overflow. You could run out of memory, but that's a different problem.

In either case, you might need to tweak the code to return exactly what you want on overflow and such.

[Source code](http://code.google.com/p/cii/) (MIT license)

That page also has a link to buy the book from amazon.com.

Comment: "Bignum" solutions are indeed possible, but I'm concerned about performance in computationally complex, interactive applications.

Answer (score 0):

Half of the requirements are satisfied in saturating arithmetic, which are implemented in e.g. ARM instructions, MMX and SSE.

As also pointed out by Stephen Canon, one needs additional elements to check overflow / NaN. Some instruction sets (Atmel at least) btw have a sticking flag to test for overflows (could be used to differentiate inf from max_int). And perhaps "Q" + 0 could mark for NaN.

Comment: You probably can't use Q to differentiate inf and NaN in truly useful fashion, as there is only a single flag, but a program will have multiple values in use at any given time, some of which may be inf/nan and some of which may be finite values.

Comment: SSE seems only capable of handling up to 16-bit integers. I wanted the full 32 on 32-bit systems and 64 on 64, respectively.